# How to implement Async Command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Although I have understood async programming with c# somehow, still don't get why async with void is not the better solution, then when I want to improve my Xamarin Forms code I found many MVVM framework use AsyncCommand to avoid void with async "unlike events" like following:

```
public class AsyncCommand : Command {
    public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute) : base(() => execute()) { }
    public AsyncCommand(Func<object, Task> execute) : base((arg) => execute(arg)) { }
}
```

But I don't know why async if command itself not async and what about use an async command with action and run a task like that:

```
public AsyncCommand(Action execute) : this(() => Task.Run(execute))
public AsyncCommand(Action<object> execute) : this((arg) => Task.Run(() => execute(arg)))
```

Comment: Note that `ICommandSource` is operating on an `ICommand` where `ICommand` only defines the synchronous `ICommand.Execute`. Unless you execute the `AsyncCommand´ from your own code the `ICommandSource` e.g. a `Button` won't await anything. it synchronously calls `ICommand.Execute`. This has the same effect as assigning an async lambda to an `Action` delegate: the lambda is also not awaited. In both cases the await chain is broken. Therefore from a `Button` perspective it doesn't matter if your command handler is `async void` or `async Task`.

Comment: Unless Microsoft introduces an official `IAsyncCommandSource` and refactors their `ICommandSource` implementations to support  `IAsyncCommandSource` (for example so that the `Button` calls `await this.Command.ExecuteAsync`) there is only a benefit for custom  `ICommandSource` implementations and for custom code that can explicitly call and await `IAsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an implementation of `AsyncCommand` that I created for this NuGet Package: [AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM](https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices).

This implementation was inspired by [@John Thiriet's](https://github.com/johnthiriet) blog post, ["Going Async With AsyncCommand"](https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An implmentation of IAsyncCommand. Allows Commands to safely be used asynchronously with Task.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class AsyncCommand<T> : IAsyncCommand<T>
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        readonly Func<T, Task> _execute;
        readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
        readonly Action<Exception> _onException;
        readonly bool _continueOnCapturedContext;
        readonly WeakEventManager _weakEventManager = new WeakEventManager();
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:TaskExtensions.MVVM.AsyncCommand`1"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The Function executed when Execute or ExecuteAysnc is called. This does not check canExecute before executing and will execute even if canExecute is false</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The Function that verifies whether or not AsyncCommand should execute.</param>
        /// <param name="onException">If an exception is thrown in the Task, <c>onException</c> will execute. If onException is null, the exception will be re-thrown</param>
        /// <param name="continueOnCapturedContext">If set to <c>true</c> continue on captured context; this will ensure that the Synchronization Context returns to the calling thread. If set to <c>false</c> continue on a different context; this will allow the Synchronization Context to continue on a different thread</param>
        public AsyncCommand(Func<T, Task> execute,
                            Func<object, bool> canExecute = null,
                            Action<Exception> onException = null,
                            bool continueOnCapturedContext = true)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute), $"{nameof(execute)} cannot be null");
            _canExecute = canExecute ?? (_ => true);
            _onException = onException;
            _continueOnCapturedContext = continueOnCapturedContext;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => _weakEventManager.AddEventHandler(value);
            remove => _weakEventManager.RemoveEventHandler(value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the command can execute in its current state
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if this command can be executed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute(parameter);

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the CanExecuteChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => _weakEventManager.HandleEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty, nameof(CanExecuteChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the Command as a Task
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The executed Task</returns>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
        public Task ExecuteAsync(T parameter) => _execute(parameter);

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is T validParameter)
                ExecuteAsync(validParameter).SafeFireAndForget(_continueOnCapturedContext, _onException);
            else if (parameter is null && !typeof(T).IsValueType)
                ExecuteAsync((T)parameter).SafeFireAndForget(_continueOnCapturedContext, _onException);
            else
                throw new InvalidCommandParameterException(typeof(T), parameter.GetType());
        }
        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An implmentation of IAsyncCommand. Allows Commands to safely be used asynchronously with Task.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        readonly Func<Task> _execute;
        readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
        readonly Action<Exception> _onException;
        readonly bool _continueOnCapturedContext;
        readonly WeakEventManager _weakEventManager = new WeakEventManager();
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:TaskExtensions.MVVM.AsyncCommand`1"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The Function executed when Execute or ExecuteAysnc is called. This does not check canExecute before executing and will execute even if canExecute is false</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The Function that verifies whether or not AsyncCommand should execute.</param>
        /// <param name="onException">If an exception is thrown in the Task, <c>onException</c> will execute. If onException is null, the exception will be re-thrown</param>
        /// <param name="continueOnCapturedContext">If set to <c>true</c> continue on captured context; this will ensure that the Synchronization Context returns to the calling thread. If set to <c>false</c> continue on a different context; this will allow the Synchronization Context to continue on a different thread</param>
        public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute,
                            Func<object, bool> canExecute = null,
                            Action<Exception> onException = null,
                            bool continueOnCapturedContext = true)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute), $"{nameof(execute)} cannot be null");
            _canExecute = canExecute ?? (_ => true);
            _onException = onException;
            _continueOnCapturedContext = continueOnCapturedContext;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => _weakEventManager.AddEventHandler(value);
            remove => _weakEventManager.RemoveEventHandler(value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the command can execute in its current state
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if this command can be executed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute(parameter);

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the CanExecuteChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => _weakEventManager.HandleEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty, nameof(CanExecuteChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the Command as a Task
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The executed Task</returns>
        public Task ExecuteAsync() => _execute();

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) => _execute().SafeFireAndForget(_continueOnCapturedContext, _onException);
        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods for System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    /// </summary>
    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Safely execute the Task without waiting for it to complete before moving to the next line of code; commonly known as "Fire And Forget". Inspired by John Thiriet's blog post, "Removing Async Void": https://johnthiriet.com/removing-async-void/.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">Task.</param>
        /// <param name="continueOnCapturedContext">If set to <c>true</c> continue on captured context; this will ensure that the Synchronization Context returns to the calling thread. If set to <c>false</c> continue on a different context; this will allow the Synchronization Context to continue on a different thread</param>
        /// <param name="onException">If an exception is thrown in the Task, <c>onException</c> will execute. If onException is null, the exception will be re-thrown</param>
        #pragma warning disable RECS0165 // Asynchronous methods should return a Task instead of void
        public static async void SafeFireAndForget(this System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool continueOnCapturedContext = true, System.Action<System.Exception> onException = null)
        #pragma warning restore RECS0165 // Asynchronous methods should return a Task instead of void
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) when (onException != null)
            {
                onException?.Invoke(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Weak event manager that allows for garbage collection when the EventHandler is still subscribed
    /// </summary>
    public class WeakEventManager
    {
        readonly Dictionary<string, List<Subscription>> _eventHandlers = new Dictionary<string, List<Subscription>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the event handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handler">Handler</param>
        /// <param name="eventName">Event name</param>
        public void AddEventHandler(Delegate handler, [CallerMemberName] string eventName = "")
    {
            if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventName));

            if (handler is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));

            EventManagerService.AddEventHandler(eventName, handler.Target, handler.GetMethodInfo(), _eventHandlers);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the event handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handler">Handler</param>
        /// <param name="eventName">Event name</param>
        public void RemoveEventHandler(Delegate handler, [CallerMemberName] string eventName = "")
        {
            if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventName));

            if (handler is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));

            EventManagerService.RemoveEventHandler(eventName, handler.Target, handler.GetMethodInfo(), _eventHandlers);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender</param>
        /// <param name="eventArgs">Event arguments</param>
        /// <param name="eventName">Event name</param>
        public void HandleEvent(object sender, object eventArgs, string eventName) => EventManagerService.HandleEvent(eventName, sender, eventArgs, _eventHandlers);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An Async implmentation of ICommand
    /// </summary>
    public interface IAsyncCommand<T> : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the Command as a Task
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The executed Task</returns>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync(T parameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An Async implmentation of ICommand
    /// </summary>
    public interface IAsyncCommand : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the Command as a Task
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The executed Task</returns>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello Brandon.I want to use it in my application, but I can't get work with CanExecute - button is not changing to enable, when condition is set. Only it works when initialize - but changes not working. Can You post an example with view how to make it works?

Comment: @Andreas_k You’ll need to call AsyncCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() each time the value of CanExecute changes. I’ve added this as an example at the bottom of the Readme for v4.0.0: https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/blob/Release-v4.0.0/README.md#asynccommand

Comment: And here is an example of how I’m using it in a sample app: https://github.com/brminnick/SimpleXamarinGraphQL/blob/e22ba2dc4666860bb54987f1ae6edc14bf9c9d62/SimpleXamarinGraphQL/ViewModels/GraphQLViewModel.cs#L23

Comment: So do I need to add that `AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM` nuget package to my project to be able to use this code? I am missing references to `EventManagerService` and `Subscription`.

Comment: Why do you call the extension `SafeFireAndForget` instead of just `FireAndForget`? What makes it _safe_?

Comment: Note that `ICommandSource` is operating on an `ICommand` where `ICommand` only defines the synchronous `ICommand.Execute`. Unless you execute the `AsyncCommand´ from your own code the `ICommandSource` e.g. a `Button` won't await anything. it synchronously calls `ICommand.Execute`. This has the same effect as assigning an async lambda to an `Action` delegate: the lambda is also not awaited. In both cases the await chain is broken. Therefore from a `Button` perspective it doesn't matter if your command handler is `async void` or `async  Task`.

Comment: Unless Microsoft introduces a `IAsyncCommandSource` and refactors their `ICommandSource` implementations to support  `IAsyncCommandSource` (so that the `Button` calls `await this.Command.ExecuteAsync`) there is only a benefit for custom  `ICommandSource` implementations and for custom code that can explicitly call and await `IAsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: `SafeFireAndForget` has a `catch when(onException != null)`. So if I don't provide a handler, the exception won't be caught at all, and instead will bubble up to the caller of the `async void`. But isn't that precisely what the `SafeFireAndForget` method was meant to **prevent** - bubbling unhandled exceptions into the UI thread, leading to an app crash?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with `async` `void` on a command execute handler providing you handle your exceptions.

So what does an `AsyncCommand`, offer? Potentially the following

- An error channel to pass back any unhandled exceptions
- Not having to write async void or async lamdas
- IsBusy framework, to stop things like double hits or what ever you can imagine

Comment: "Total benefit? Next to zero" are you sure about that?

Comment: I am puzzled by your statement that the total benefit is "next to zero", immediately after listing 3 possible benefits. Defining a custom class to give a central place to inject exception handling - without cluttering each call site - seems quite useful to me. Is your point that no framework built-in class would be likely to provide significant benefit? That this is a situation where it needs to be up to each programmer to decide if it is worth writing a custom class to handle their requirements?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeah i should really remove the last part. There are benefits in certain areas

Comment: There is no big benefit when the `ICommand` is used with the `ICommandSource` of the WPF ljbrary. The point is that `ICommand` only defines a synchronous `Execute` method. And `ICommandSource´ expects to handle an ´ICommand`. This means not matter your `IAsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync` implementation the `ICommandSource` e.g. `Button` won't await your command. The call to `ICommand.Execute` is always synchronous. AsyncCommand usually calls `ExecuteAsync` from the `ICommand.Execute` method. It's the same as when assigning an async lambda to an Action delegate. The await chain is broken.

Comment: So unless you call `IAsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync` from your own code explicitly, there is no difference in assigning a `async void` command handler.

Answer (score 4):

To anyone interested: Brandons solution above does not requery the CanExecute automatically and requires RaiseCanExecuteChanged(). To change this, you can exchange

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => _weakEventManager.AddEventHandler(value);
        remove => _weakEventManager.RemoveEventHandler(value);
    }
```

with

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
```

and remove

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => _weakEventManager.HandleEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty, nameof(CanExecuteChanged));
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: What is `CommandManager` and what does it do differently from the original implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid async void occurrences in your code (exceptions of event handlers).

Please refer [this blog from Stephen for more detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an
>   exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that
>   exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void
>   methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an
>   async void method will be raised directly on the
>   SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method
>   started.

[image]

Comment: as you wrote - `exceptions of event handlers` and `ICommand\IAsyncCommand` is also exceptional case, it's event handlers for `mvvm` in `wpf`