# MvvmCross MvxAsyncCommand CanExecute does not disable/enable attached button

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross in a Xamarin.Forms solution.  I have the command attached to the button with the following code

```
 <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

The command is setup in the ViewModel like so

```
private ICommand _loginCommand;
        public ICommand LoginCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _loginCommand = _loginCommand ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(Login,
                    () =>
                    {
                        return IsOnline;
                    });
                return _loginCommand;
            }
        }
```

I then query when the network connection changes which should in turn change the boolean returned in the CanExecute Func in the MvxAsyncCommand.

```
        {
            base.OnlineSignalChanged(isOnline);
            (LoginCommand as MvxAsyncCommand)?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();  //tried calling other methods here as well in case I was calling the wrong thing
        }
```

In that last code block I am able to stop a breakpoint to see that the CanExecute is queried again.  However, the button is not enabled/disabled properly.

Is this a know issue with MvvmCross implementation of MvxAsyncCommand?  I ended up using the advice of the following thread use John Thiriet version of an AsyncCommand and all works well.

[How to implement Async Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232156/how-to-implement-async-command)

Comment: You should use `IMvxAsyncCommand` as your command property, also you sould declare the implementation apart from your command property, check this sample on the [MvvmCross Playgroud Project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Core/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs). Remember you can always check the [Playground project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground) to find how to use the features.

Comment: @FabriBertani those edits did not hel. I changed references to ICommand to IMvxAsyncCommand.  I also moved the () => return IsOnline function to its own method.

Comment: @DeanRich As a seasoned .Net MVVM developer i can give you the advice: what you've written is totally valid and would have worked in a normal MVVM Library. MVX is quite strange. I'm sitting for 30 min at the same problem and no solution so far.